# Twitter API: How to make query keep running?

Tags: python-3.x, api, dataframe, twitter, twitterapi-python

Novice programmer here seeking help.

I already set up my code to my requirements to use the Twitter's premium API.

```
SEARCH_TERM = '#AAPL OR #FB OR #KO OR #ABT OR #PEPCO'
PRODUCT = 'fullarchive'
LABEL = 'my_label'
r = api.request('tweets/search/%s/:%s' % (PRODUCT, LABEL), 
                {'query':SEARCH_TERM, 'fromDate':201501010000, 'toDate':201812310000})
```

However, when I run it I obtain the maximum number of tweets per search which is 500. 
My question is should I add to the query maxResults = 500? And how do I use the next parameter to keep the code running until all the tweets that correspond to my query are obtained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To up the results from the default of 100 to 500, yes, add `maxResults` to the query like this:

```
r = api.request('tweets/search/%s/:%s' % (PRODUCT, LABEL), 
    {
        'query':SEARCH_TERM, 
        'fromDate':201501010000, 'toDate':201812310000,
        'maxResults':500
    })
```

You can make successive queries to get more results by using the `next` parameter. But, even easier, you can let [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI) do this for you by using the `TwitterPager` class. Here is an example:

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI, TwitterPager
SEARCH_TERM = '#AAPL OR #FB OR #KO OR #ABT OR #PEPCO'
PRODUCT = 'fullarchive'
LABEL = 'my_label'
api = TwitterAPI(<consumer key>, 
                 <consumer secret>,
                 <access token key>,
                 <access token secret>)
pager = TwitterPager(api, 'tweets/search/%s/:%s' % (PRODUCT, LABEL), 
    {
        'query':SEARCH_TERM, 
        'fromDate':201501010000, 'toDate':201812310000
    })
for item in pager.get_iterator():
    print(item['text'] if 'text' in item else item)
```

This example will keep making successive requests with the `next` parameter until no tweets can be downloaded.

Comment: Hello! By using the iterator does it automatically take per query the 500 tweets or should I specify the maxResults?

Comment: You would need to specify 500 with `maxResults`. Otherwise, you will download batches of 100 tweets.

Answer (score 0):

Use the count variable in a raw_query, for example:

```
results = api.GetSearch(
    raw_query="q=twitter%20&result_type=recent&since=2014-07-19&count=100")
```